# Must I override integer __add__ method to support addition of an integer and object?

Tags: python, addition, magic-methods

So I am making a class called Complex which a representation of imaginary numbers (I know python has its own, but i want to make one myself). Thing is I want to construct an **add** method that supports addition of complex numbers as well as integers. So:

```py
a = Complex(2, 4) + Complex(1, 1)
b = Complex(0, 3) + 3
c = 2 + Complex(4, 5)
```

should all be supported. As I understand,

```py
object1 + object2
```

is the syntactic-sugar-equivalent of

```py
object1.__add__(object2)
```

First and second examples are fine, but how do I get my class to support addition on the form INTEGER + COMPLEX? Do I have to override integer __add__method, if so; how do I do that, and is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to implement `__radd__` on `Complex`.

the way this works is pretty cool, if there's no existing implementation on an object for `__add__`, in your case, `int` + `Complex`, python will automatically check to see if `__radd__` is implemented on the right-hand object.

so it would be like:

```
- does `int` have `__add__` for `Complex`? no
- does `Complex` have `__radd__` for `int`? yes. cool, we've solved it
```

the implementation would probably look something like:

```
class Complex:
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + Complex(other)
```